# react native expo api post issue

Tags: reactjs, react-native, fetch, expo

**Network request failed
at node_modules/whatwg-fetch/dist/fetch.umd.js:535:17 in setTimeout$argument_0
at [native code]:null in callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue**

```
const [email, setEmail] = React.useState('')
const [pass, setPass] = React.useState('')
const [login, setLogin] = React.useState({
  email1: 'bilal',
  pass1: 'hadid',
})
const [respData, setRespData] = React.useState()
const [respStatus, setRespStatus] = React.useState()
console.log(email, pass)
React.useEffect(() => {
 let formData = new FormData()
 formData.append('username', 'bilal@gmail.com')
 formData.append('password', 'hadid')
 fetch('https://aic-developments.xyz/v1/login_user.php', {
   method: 'POST',
   body: formData,
  })
  .then((resp) => resp.json())
  .then((respJSon) => {
    console.log(login)
    console.log(respJSon)
    setRespData(respJSon.messege)
    setRespStatus(respJSon.status)
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err)
  })
})


[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NEMpo.png
[enter image description here][1]
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is causing the issue but there's something wrong with your code. The way you wrote that useEffect will cause an infinite loop. Read about useEffect dependencies array and try this:

```js
const [email, setEmail] = React.useState('')
const [pass, setPass] = React.useState('')
const [login, setLogin] = React.useState({
  email1: 'bilal',
  pass1: 'hadid',
})
const [respData, setRespData] = React.useState()
const [respStatus, setRespStatus] = React.useState()
console.log(email, pass)
React.useEffect(() => {
 let formData = new FormData()
 formData.append('username', 'bilal@gmail.com')
 formData.append('password', 'hadid')
 fetch('https://aic-developments.xyz/v1/login_user.php', {
   method: 'POST',
   body: formData,
  })
  .then((resp) => resp.json())
  .then((respJSon) => {
    console.log(login)
    console.log(respJSon)
    setRespData(respJSon.messege)
    setRespStatus(respJSon.status)
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err)
  })
},[])
```